# Python place quote around csv cells containing comma

Tags: python, csv

Python: v 3.6

---

**Update:**

I'm trying code where EVERYTHING is quoted, i.e. `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`. For some reason even that is not working, i.e. file is outputting, but WITHOUT quotes.

If this can be resolved, it may help with the remaining question.

Code

```
import csv

in_path = "eateries.csv"

with open(in_path,"r") as infile, open("out.csv","w", newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

[image]

---

**Original Question:**

I am trying to write python script that reads csv file and outputs csv file. In output, cells with comma (",") will have quotes

Input:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Actual Output:

[image]

Below is code, please assist

```
import csv


in_path = "eateries.csv"
with open(in_path,"r") as infile, open("out.csv","w", newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=",", quotechar=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

Comment: Why did you set `quotechar` to `,`?

Comment: @melpomene I thought QUOTE_MINIMAL will quote csv entries of special character, specified by `quotechar`. In this case, I wish to quote csv entries that contain `,`

Comment: The input/output of this program is text. Why did you post screenshots of some spreadsheet application instead of actual input/output?

Comment: @melpomene because when you double-click on the `.csv`, that's what happens?

Comment: @melpomene In past screenshots have always been helpful to those answering any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quotechar` doesn't mean "quote this character". It means "this is the character you use to quote things".

You do not want to use commas to quote things. Remove `quotechar=","`.

---

With `quotechar` corrected, your CSV will quote field values that have commas in them, but importing the CSV into Excel or some other spreadsheet application may not produce cell values with quotation marks. (Also, `eateries.csv` probably had quoting already.) It is quite likely that you don't actually *need* quotes in Excel or whatever your spreadsheet app is; the fact that the value is in a single cell instead of spread across multiple is the spreadsheet version of quoting.

Comment: Well the actual CSV has over million lines, hence cannot be imported into Excel. On the other hand, I need CSV for Excel's Power Query. Unless I place quotes around cells with comma, the data renders incorrectly. I tried Excel's search function but computer freezes, hence trying Python.

Comment: This answers my original question (sort of). Will post follow-up question later.